# Computer not reading OS-disks

Tags: operating-systems, dvd

My computer is a mess and I want to reformat it (it's a win 7 installation). I have a dvd that I know has a working copy of windows (I can open the setup on another computer). However, in the computer I want to reformat it doesn't manage to read the disk at all. If I try to open it inside my computer, it just ejects the disk. Here's the strange thing, however. My computer is able to read any other cd's, like a video game disk or whatever.

Do you have any idea what causes this? What can I do about it?

System info:

Windows 7, home edition (64-bit, alienware version). The computer is an alienware m17x r2.

Comment: Not rrying to be insulting, but sometimes it are the little things. You wrote: `My computer is able to read other CD's`.  Did you also check that it was able to read other **DVDs**?

Comment: Remember that you can always use a bootable USB stick if all fails.

Comment: @Hennes Well, if you look at my comment to the one answer I managed to make it read the disk at one point, but that was just by restarting MANY times. I'm just hoping it'll read it until I get around to formatting it.

Comment: @RsyaStudios Yep, that was my go-to-plan.

Comment: If you have another computer (or can borrow a friends computer). Get the iso image of the DVD and copy it to an USB pen drive. Then you can boot from that. (This is probably what @Rsya meant).

Comment: If your computer ejects the disk on its own when trying to be read, the disk may be off-balance.  Usually when a disk can't be read it will just stay inside being useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't identify exactly why it happened, but rebooting quite a few times eventually solved it.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely the disc has scratches on it, the other computer that it does work on may have a better (or slower speed) dvd-drive which is why it works there.

Create an ISO of your installation dis, and burn it to a new blank dvd (it will fit on a 4.7gb disc). Use the burned copy to install Windows.

Comment: It just randomly worked after a bunch of restarts. Now I've reformatted so I don't really know what to do with this question. None of the answers are really applicable (the cd isn't damaged or anything, my computer was just fu**** up).

Comment: @user2875994 It appears you've solved the problem yourself; you can post your own answer and mark it as accepted (eg: appears to be a random glitch, but reboots eventually solved it). If you feel your answer is weak, use wiki-mode to entice expansion edits. Glad to hear you got things working. :)

Answer (score 3):

I have a DVD drive that acts strange too: it reads and writes discs from only one manufacturer. All the others are not seen at all or ejected when I double click them in My Computer.

It's a DVD drive issue. Most probably there's dust inside the drive. It is possible that the laser lens or the entire laser module is not "moving" as it should - it is not synchronized with the disc thus it skips data.

And it probably can't get at the beginning of the disc as it doesn't recognize discs at all.

Comment: I actually got it to read my disk at some point after a restart, but I didn't really do anything. I can't reformat it just yet since due to reasons (I hope to do it sometime next week), so I'm just hoping it doesn't stop working again before I get around to reformatting it (and that my computer survives the process. It's basically at it's deathbed with 90% of my applications crashing at startup).

Comment: I wouldn't dream of touching it yet, with an intermittent DVD. Get the USB stick made & checked first.